# Should i have different icon sizes for android app project

Tags: android, android-layout

Should i maintain 4 or 5 sizes of each icon for ldpi, hdpi, mdpi, xdpi and xxdpi?  One icon which is 48x48(any other size -hight resolution) is not enough for all different size?  I have lot of icons. I feel my app size will be increased.

Please suggest me. Thanks

Comment: definitely don't need 5 different sets of icons. I'd suggest 2 or 3 sets that in total make up your entire icon library. I would hit the higher density displays because they will look the worse if you leave them out.

Answer (score 2):

if you dont want android to automatically scale your image size ( which will look ugly because you will lose quality), you should have different icons for different screen sizes, for example mdi - 32x32, hdpi 48x48, xhdpi 64x64..

Comment: I would add that a 24x24 icon may not simply be a scaled 64x64 icon, it may need some more graphic works to make it look fine, which explains the need for multiple icon size.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep different versions, yes. In fact, if you work on Eclipse, you can hit Ctrl+N, go to the **Android** list, **Android Icon Set**, and then select Launcher Icon. It will create different resolutions of your icon, plus one for the Google Play website.